# Differentiating expression involving summation

Tags: derivatives, summation

My problem seemed very simple at glance but I keep missing one term from the answer. Any suggestions?

This is the problem:

> We have
>   $$x_i^* + \xi_i + \frac{\alpha_i}{p_i} \left[ y - \sum_{j=1}^n p_j \xi_j \right]$$
>   and we need to get the following
>   $$\frac{\partial{x_i^*}}{\partial{p_i}} = -\frac{\alpha_i}{p_i} \left[\xi_i + \frac{y-\sum_{j=1}^n p_j \xi_j}{p_i}\right]$$

whilst I get the following
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial x_i^*}{p_i}
&= -\left[y - \sum_{j=1}^n p_j \epsilon_j \right] \alpha_i p_i^{-2} (-\epsilon_i) \\
&= \frac{\epsilon_i \alpha_i}{p_i^2} \left[y - \sum_{j=1}^n p_j \epsilon_j \right]
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You took the derivative of both factors and multiplied them together, which is incorrect. You need to use the product rule.

Comment: still missing the answer.

Comment: I don't doubt it; I explained why.